# PowerBi Measure - divide by value based on another value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following dataset.

```
    name            duration    date        begintime   time_type
    Person 1        15          20190910    0845        AM  
    Person 1        15          20190910    1000        OV  
    Person 1        15          20190910    1100        AM  
    Person 2        15          20190910    0915        AM  
    Person 2        15          20190910    1015        AM  
    Person 2        15          20190910    0945        AM  
    Person 2        15          20190910    1045        AM
```

I trying to create a measure that will sum the duration by person, but because Person 1 has time type of OV on 20190910, I need to divide the sum by 5. If the person doesn't have a time type of OV for that day, I will need to divide by 8 (as Person 2 does not have time type of OV on that day). It is possible that Person 1 doesn't have a time type of OV on another day, but for that day I will need to divide by 8. How can I accomplish this in a PowerBi Measure?

UPDATE:
The expedected output should looks like this:

```
Person 1 - 9    (15 + 15 + 15) / 5
Person 2 - 7.5  (15 + 15 + 15 + 15) / 8
```

Comment: Can you show what your expected output looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This measure will check if the values present in the context contain "OV", and based on that will choose the proper value for the division

```
Measure = 
SUM('Table'[duration]) /
IF(CONTAINSROW(VALUES('Table'[time_type]),"OV")
   ,5 --true
   ,8 --false
)
```

Comment: the expected results, I am looking for doesn't match. the problem with this is the rule is I have to sum all the hours for the day divide 5 if there are EXT for that day. your measure divides by 8 and 5 for that day....

Comment: ok, I didn't interpret the question correctly, I've edited the answer and now the formula returns what you expect

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario, you apply the division on a daily basis, therefore the adjusted divisor can be different in different days. Then you should also interate over names, otherwise totals would be incorrect.

```
Adjusted Duration = 
SUMX( 
    VALUES( TImes[name] ),
    SUMX(
        VALUES( Times[date] ),
        VAR timeTypeOV =
            CALCULATE(
                COUNTROWS( Times ),
                ALLEXCEPT( Times, Times[name], Times[date] ),
                Times[time_type] = "OV"
            )
        VAR duration =
            CALCULATE(
                SUM( Times[duration] ),
                ALLEXCEPT( Times, Times[name], Times[date] )
            )
        VAR divisor =
            IF( timeTypeOV > 0, 5, 8 )
        RETURN
            DIVIDE( duration, divisor )
    )
)
```

Comment: here is the code to create the sample Times table, and the measure definition too https://pastebin.com/d9a8C4yZ